# Ubuntu, MySQL - проблемы с кодировкой

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu, кодировка, utf-8

Поставил на Ubuntu сервер MySQL, создал БД, при создании указал кодировку utf-8:

```
create database my_bd_name default character set utf8;
```

Из дампа импортировал туда 2 таблицы. В той таблице, где у меня есть русские буквы, при просмотре данных таблицы отображаются "кракозябры". Прилагаю скрин:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Когда создавал эту таблицу еще через Workbench, указывал кодировку utf-8. Не пойму почему могла возникнуть такая проблема. С английскими значениями все в порядке.

Comment: Попробуй создать БД типа InnoDB с кодировкой UTF8 и заполни её данными. Если при SELECT будет так же - значит проблема точно не в сервере.

Comment: Какова кодировка терминала? Похоже, что однобайтная

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам необходимо изменить кодировку терминала `putty` на `utf-8`.
База отдаёт строки в корректной кодировке, просто терминал не может её отобразить.

---

Установить по умолчанию:
`Putty Configuration` - `Window` - `Translation`:
`Received data assumed to be in which character set:` = `UTF-8`

Comment: Спасибо, действительно проблема была в этом! :)

Comment: utf-8 кодировка в однобайтном представлении имеет узнаваемые паттерны - это много повторяющихся через один символов-префиксов. В вашем случае - символы `п` и `я`

Comment: спасибо, буду иметь в виду